# How to watch for changes in an array of objects without causing massive lag?

Tags: angular, angular2-docheck

I feel there are some things that are missing in Angular 2 that Angular 1 had, one of those things being the `$watch` function.

`OnChanges` and `DoCheck` are supposed to replace the `$watch` but I haven't been able to use either to get the desired result. `OnChanges` can't listen to objects so that's of no use in this scenario, and while `DoCheck` does the job, it causes massive lag since it seems to go bananas as soon as a change happens.

Here I've got a component which has a bunch of checkboxes, each checkbox toggle causes a value to be added to an array, rather than the default `true/false` functionality.

What I need to watch for in this component is the `isDisabled` state of a checkbox, so each time it changes I need to update the `isChecked` state of the `checkbox`.

Like I said, it works, but it has 2-3 seconds of delay on every checkbox toggle, despite only having 5 checkboxes. Preferably I wouldn't want the loop to run every time you toggle a checkbox, but instead only if the `isDisabled` state of a checkbox changes.

**EDIT**: I was told an `Observable` could do the job here, but I can't find any examples of this being applied to an array of objects like this. It also needs to trigger without calling its `next()` method manually, since it has to listen for outside changes to the array that is being sent in.

**EDIT 2**: I created a plunkr which doesn't show the lag, probably because in my app I have other things that might have an affect on the delay as well. However, the plunkr clearly shows that there seems to be something wrong because I put a `console.log(true)` within the `ngDoCheck()` function and it runs a looot of times. Which can't be intended, if it is, it's really odd.

Here's the plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/dJVnqbrredDyWTXNDzDK?p=preview

How can I do this?

```
export class FormCheckboxMultipleComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  @Input() model: Array<any>;
  @Output('modelChange') onModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  @Output() callback: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

  constructor(private _globals: GlobalVariablesService) {
    this.ns = _globals.ns;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.model = this.model || [];
  }

  ngDoCheck() {

    for (let checkbox of this.checkboxes) {

      if (checkbox.isDisabled) {
        this.untoggle(checkbox);
      }
    }
  }

  findIndex(checkbox) {

    return this.model.reduce(function(cur, val, index) {

      if (val.name === checkbox.name && cur === -1) {
        return index;
      }

      return cur;
    }, -1);
  }

  addToModel(checkbox) {
    this.model.push(checkbox);
  }

  removeFromModel(i) {
    this.model.splice(i, 1);
  }

  toggle(checkbox) {

    if (checkbox.isDisabled) {
      return false;
    }

    let existingIndex = this.findIndex(checkbox);

    if (existingIndex === -1) {
      this.addToModel(checkbox);
    }
    else {
      this.removeFromModel(existingIndex);
    }

    checkbox.isChecked = !checkbox.isChecked;

    this.onModelChange.emit(this.model);

    this.callback ? this.callback.emit() : false;
  }

  untoggle(checkbox) {

    let existingIndex = this.findIndex(checkbox);

    this.removeFromModel(existingIndex);

    checkbox.isChecked = false;

    this.onModelChange.emit(this.model);
  }
}
```

Comment: You could just us an `Observable` to notify about changes instead or in addition to the array change. This is the way in Angular2 to avoid expensive deep value compairsons.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer I'm having problems understanding how to use Observables despite looking at countless examples, could you provide an example that would work in this component? Would really appreciate it.

Comment: Maybe you are running into https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/3406 otherwise with 5 checkboxes a delay should hardly be measureable.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can an Observable's subscribe method run without me manually calling .next()?

Comment: I don't know rxjs observable very well because I use Dart which has streams for this. AFAIK you can create an observable from events which then emits values automatically. Don't know details though.

Comment: "it causes massive lag since it seems to go bananas as soon as a change happens" -- can you create a minimal plunker that demonstrates this?  Like Günter said, I don't see how checking 5 objects could cause a multi-second delay.

Comment: @MarkRajcok I will try whenever I find the time.

Comment: @MarkRajcok Look in the plunkr and open the console, and you can see it "go bananas", without lag however, but in a larger application such as the demo app I got it will cause lag.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Can you take a look? https://plnkr.co/edit/dJVnqbrredDyWTXNDzDK?p=preview It doesn't show the lag but it does show the ngDoCheck going bonkers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's caused by `this.onModelChange.emit(this.model);` in `this.untoggle(checkbox)` in `ngDoCheck`. This is a perfect endless loop. `this.onModelChange.emit(this.model);` causes change detection and therefore `ngDoCheck()` to run and the loop begins again.

Ensure that change detection doesn't cause change detection. `ngDoCheck` is called by change detection and must not invoke another change detection otherwise you get an endless loop.

[**Plunker**](https://plnkr.co/edit/OAOOh0FqvXBrclhL11ZM?p=preview)

Comment: I just did model changes in ngDoCheck and emitted it and it doesn't cause an infinite loop this time... freaking odd.

Comment: I guess this would also need closer investigation.

Comment: I made a plunkr with the updated version, but I get some weird zone error: https://plnkr.co/edit/arROwxsFYraSBeAZCIYF?p=preview

Comment: The `GlobalsVariablesService` is only in the constructor parameter but I haven't found the class nor is it provided anywhere.

Comment: Why is all this code necessary anyway? I couldn't make any sense of all these methods.  Why do you implement `ngDoCheck`?

Comment: It's needed if you dynamically add/remove checkboxes, then it has to check its state and add/remove it to the model based on it.

Comment: Why is this necessary for checkboxes?

Comment: When you set a checkbox to true, its value gets added to the model which is an array, as opposed to having multiple checkboxes that are just true/false. Makes sense?

Comment: Perhaps it's fine to change the model in `ngDoCheck` just not in a way that produces cycles. Sorry, I guess I'm too tired already today.

Comment: I'll investigate further, at least your answer led me to a working solution (for now), perhaps you should take a day off from SO ;)

Comment: It's late in the evening here anyway :o

Comment: @MarkRajcok That change detection is re-run is actually caused by `this.onModelChange.emit(this.model);`. I updated my answer. Thanks for the hint.